# How to study Sodium hypochlorite stability with materials

Tags: materials, stability

first of all I'm not not sure to be in the right stack exchange site, but I'm a material engineering student and this year I have a project: choose a material for a container filled with Sodium hypochlorite, my university has given us CES Edupack, that contains a lot of infomartion about mechanical and physical properties, but nothing about material stability.
Since we haven't done any lecture about materials stability/decomposition, I'm here to ask if there is someone that could enlight me about how to proceed to evaluate the stability of a material.
The only thing that I came across while thinking about it is to avoid materials(polymers) that has got active groups with Sodium hypochlorite, is it a good approch?

**EDIT**
Maybe my question is a little dispersive so I make it clear here: my main concert is more general: how do I study the stability of sodium hypochlorite inside the container? What should I check to be sure that the container doesn't "melt"?

Comment: Welcome to Chemistry.SE! To acquaint yourself with this page, take the [tour](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/help). Furthermore [this tutorial](http://meta.chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/88/189) shows you how math and chemical formulae can be nicely formatted on this site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sodium Hypochlorite  is soluble in water and reacts with all organic solvents. Sodium hypochlorite is extensively used in house-holds as a bleaching agent and it is a chemical compound with formula $\ce{NaClO}$.

Household sodium hypochlorite bleach was introduced to Americans in 1909 and sold in steel containers, then in glass bottles. In the early 1960s, the introduction of the plastic jug brought a cheaper, lighter, and nonbreakable packaging alternative. It reduced transportation costs and protected the safety of workers involved in its shipping and handling. Additionally, the thick plastic did not permit ultraviolet light to reach the bleach, which improved its chemical stability and effectiveness. In recent years, how-ever, plastic containers have become an environmental concern because of the time it takes the material to decompose in a landfill. Many companies that depend on plastic packaging, including bleach manufacturers, have begun to reduce the amount of plastic in their packaging or to use recycled plastics. In the early 1990s, Clorox introduced post-consumer resins (PCR) in its packaging. The newer bottles are a blend of virgin high-density polyethylene (HDPE) and 25% recycled plastic, primarily from clear milk jug-type bottles.

Read more: http://www.madehow.com/Volume-2/Bleach.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but my main concert is more genera: how do I study the stability of sodium hypochlorite inside the container? What should I check to be sure that the container doesn't decompone?

Comment: To keep sodium hypochlorite solution stable, protect it from light,including direct sunrays and store it separated from acids.

Comment: To be sure that the container doesn't decompose, I propose to monitor the composition of hypochlorite solution using gas phase chromatography GPC or HPLC.